# How to disable popups on Webbrowser control and navigate Webbrowser to New url?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I tried some methods they didn't work.It still popups new page on the Internet explorer.

Here is my method but it didn't work.

```
 private string strURL;
    private void webbMain_NewWindow2(object ppDisp, bool Cancel)
    {
        Cancel = true;
        webbMain.Navigate(strURL);
    }
    private void WebbMain_StatusTextChange(string Text)
    {
        strURL = Text;
    }
```